# Как сделать чтобы ui кнопка срабатывала не тогда когда я отпускаю мышку, а тогда когда я только нажимаю

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Я в своей игре сделал кнопку прыжка, и мне нужно, чтобы функция срабатывала как только я нажимаю на эту кнопку. Но в ui button функция срабатывает после того, как я отпускаю мышку с нее. А мне обязательно нужно именно так, чтобы кнопка срабатывала именно по нажатию

Comment: используй OnPointerClick

Comment: Самый лёгкий способ: подключать компонент `EventTrigger` и использовать оттуда обработчик `OnMouseDown`

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ControlLeft : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //делаем что то при нажатии
    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //делаем что то при отжатии
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если делать в инспекторе то можно использовать компонент EventTrigger.
Нажмите на кнопке Add Component и далее по списку:
AddComponent --> EventTrigger --> AddNewEventType --> PointerDown --> +
В поле вставляйте свои функции.